# trouble with nltk tags

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I am trying to tag a set of words as a part of speech using NLTK then save the word in a file.  It seems to work for VB as a keyword and NN but I cannot get VBD to work. It returns an empty set.

```
import nltk
f = open("F:\\...\\testFile.txt", "r")
fp = open("F:\\...\\writeToSmaller.txt","w")
dctRead = f.read()
lines = dctRead
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(lines)
verbs = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokenized) if(pos[:2] == 'VB')]
fp.write(str(verbs))
f.close()
fp.close()
```

is my keyword list wrong, I am using this list. (only an excerpt of the list).  The list is from [Categorizing and POS Tagging with NLTK Python](https://medium.com/@muddaprince456/categorizing-and-pos-tagging-with-nltk-python-28f2bc9312c3)
VB verb, base form take
VBD verb, past tense, took
VBG verb, gerund/present participle taking
VBN verb, past participle is taken
VBP verb, sing. present, known-3d take
VBZ verb, 3rd person sing. present takes

Comment: Why do you think `VBD` tag is applicable and correct tag for any of the verbs in your data? You can illustrate with example from your dataset to confirm that it is indeed an expected output.

Comment: Try making a simpler example to debug like `print(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize('He ran to the grocery store.')))`.

Comment: I did use smaller programs and it comes to this;  There should be a past tense form because I put a past tense form in the file.  This is the file contents:  the lemmas are robust and have great legs. They run ran running person cat dog john took.  My problem is with the keyword not the verbage of the program

Comment: I don't think you understand how part of speech taggers work. They depend on context to inform the tagging. Because your text is word salad instead of natural English, the model will suffer when it runs into a past tense word where it's unnatural.